# react native google calendar

Tags: react-native, google-calendar-api

I searching like crazy to find a package for react native that can work with google calendar, getting event data and display that separately (title, description, etc).
Does anybody know a package for react native?

Cheers,

Comment: I believe you have seen this https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen that one as well, although it doesn't mention google anywhere, so I am not sure if it can work with google calendar.

Comment: What about integrating Google Calendar API https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ with your app?

Comment: Thanks again, I have looked at it and found this link: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/nodejs that seems to be as close to react native as possible.

Comment: I have tried to use the link I posted above here with the nodejs, but I am unable to get it working in react native. Anybody got this working?

Comment: @udarts have you figure out solution of google calendar api?

Comment: Desperately waiting a solution!

Comment: Found any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using react-native-calendar, but created a code for myself, see the code I used here: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/416#issuecomment-413202491

Comment: Do you know how to get a list of shared calendars using the api? The docs are very confusing

Comment: @Bomber I am not using multiple calendars yet, still looking for that option as well. I just use 1 calendar for now.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one more package, it works similar to Google calendar with custom events and modes day, week, month**

```
npm i react-native-big-calendar
```

https://react-native-big-calendar.vercel.app/?path=/story/full-customization--main

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -2):

If you are using [Expo](http://expo.io), you can try this. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/calendar.html

Expo has `createCalendarAsync`, `getCalendarsAsync`, `updateCalendarAsync` and other apis that work for you. Hope that helps.