# React-Native Google calendar Api Error "this.gapi not loaded"

Tags: android, ios, react-native, google-calendar-api

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-calendar-api for google calendar api.
also i'm using `Xcode10` & latest `React-native` Version.

This is my `Home.js` configuration:

```
import React, { Component,ReactNode,SyntheticEvent } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import ApiCalendar from 'react-google-calendar-api';

export default class Home extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.handleItemClick = this.handleItemClick.bind(this);
        }

       handleItemClick(event: SyntheticEvent<any>, name: string): void {
        if (name === 'sign-in') {
        ApiCalendar.handleAuthClick();
        } else if (name === 'sign-out') {
          ApiCalendar.handleSignoutClick();
        }
      }

      render(): ReactNode {
            return (
              <Button
              onPress={(e) => this.handleItemClick(e, 'sign-in')}
              title="Click here for Google SignIn"
              color="#841584"
              accessibilityLabel="Learn more about Google SignIn button"
              />
              );
          }
}
```

as mention in [react-google-calendar-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-calendar-api) everything i did but no result till now.

I got error in Debugging[ApiCalendar.js]

> Error: this.gapi not loaded.

I did some research on google but mostly got `ReactJS` solution not in `react-native` for this type of error.

Help is needed Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47023556/react-native-google-calendar) @Jyot